# How to access folder via browser if codeigniter project exists?

Tags: php, codeigniter, vps

I have codeigniter project lets say example.com. In my public_html folder on my server, i created a folder called test and i want to be able to access some file via the web using example.com/test/somefile.php

Since i also have a codeigniter project in the same public_html directory, i always get a codeigniter page not found error when i try example.com/test/somefile.php.

How can i basically tell my server or codeigniter project that the folder "test" is not part of the codeigniter app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` at the root of `public_html`, you probably have something like this for routing everything through index.php:

Example taken from the CI user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

```
RewriteEngine on
# If the path doesn't start with one of these...
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
# ...send the request to index.php/REQUEST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Just add "test" to the pipe delimited group, or whatever you need to do to allow access to the directory with your configuration:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|test|images|robots\.txt)
#                            ^^^^
```

Without this CI requires `index.php` in the URL - there's no way to actually have your Codeigniter app itself redirect, rewrite URLs, or block access to the `/test` directory, it's generally all done through an `.htaccess` file.